# Unable to assign or populate a list into a class

Tags: apex, list, data

I have the following classes (simplified) which I hope will convey enough information to make it clear the issue I am having.  I believe the issue in the Role_Definition class where I defined a list which I believe is correct.

In the Process_Data class specifically in the inner for loop I want to populate the data and assign but I am getting the **error**: `variable does not exist: RD_memberType_record`.  I am not too familiar with working with list in this manner so I suspect it is somehow related.

What am I missing?

```
public Data_Def
{
    public class Role_Definition
    {
        public String Name;
        public List<RD_MemberTypes> memberTypes;
    }

    public class RD_MemberTypes
    {
        public RD_MemberType memberType;
    }

    public class RD_MemberType
    {
        public String name;
    }
}
```

---

```
public Process_Data
{
    List<Role_Definition__c> lstRoleDefinition = Helper.get_Role_Definition(ids);
    for (Role_Definition__c Role_Definition_Row : lstRoleDefinition)
    {
        DataDef.Role_Definition Role_Definition_Record = New DataDef.Role_Definition();
        Role_Definition_Record.id = Role_Definition_Row.id;
        Role_Definition_Record.Name = Role_Definition_Row.Name;

        List<Membership_Type_Role__c> lstMembership_Type_Role = Helper.get_membership_type_roles_by_rolename(Role_Definition_Row.Name);
        for (Membership_Type_Role__c MTR_Row : lstMembership_Type_Role)
        {
            DataDef.RD_MemberTypes RD_memberTypes_record = New DataDef.RD_MemberTypes();
            RD_memberTypes_record.id = MTR_Row.id;
        }

        Role_Definition_Record.memberTypes = RD_memberTypes_record;  
        //Error: Variable deos not exist: RD_memberTypes_record
        strJSON = JSON.serializepretty ( Role_Definition_Record );
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you are missing few things in your code, unless you have posted here only partial detail or I am missing something badly here. I see you are missing class definition on both the classes, so looks like this should not even compile. Then your Process_Data is a class or method is not very clear, because it does not specify that. And considering if everything you wanted to post is right, then I don't see an id variable in the RD_MemberTypes. So if you can update the code snippets with more detail, that will help anyone out here to be able to provide some recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple issue in variable scoping (well, the error at least, there are other logic/semantic errors too).

Let's take a look at the last parts of your provided code

```
for (Membership_Type_Role__c MTR_Row : lstMembership_Type_Role)
{
    // The RD_memberTypes_record is defined inside of a loop
    // That means the "scope" of the variable is limited to this loop
    DataDef.RD_MemberTypes RD_memberTypes_record = New DataDef.RD_MemberTypes();
    RD_memberTypes_record.id = MTR_Row.id;
}

// Outside of the loop, RD_memberTypes_record is "out of scope", i.e. inaccessible
Role_Definition_Record.memberTypes = RD_memberTypes_record;  
strJSON = JSON.serializepretty ( Role_Definition_Record );
```

There are some other logical issues too.

`Role_Definition_Record.memberTypes` is a `List`, you can't assign a single record to it. By that, I mean...

```
List<String> myList = 'hello world!';
```

is not valid syntax

Instead, you need to initialize the list using the `new` keyword (just like you would for any other object)

```
// This isn't the only way to initialize a list, but it's the most common one
List<String> myList = new List<String>();
```

What you'll want to do is:

- initialize your list outside of the loop
- then, inside the loop, add instances of the appropriate data type (`DataDef.RD_MemberTypes` here) to the list using the `.add()` method

+edit: spelling things out some more

```
// You're creating a new instance of your Role_Definition class
// This class contains 2 variables, Name (a string) and memberTypes (a list)
DataDef.Role_Definition role_Definition_Record = New DataDef.Role_Definition();

// This line is invalid in your given example, since Role_Definition does not contain
// an Id variable
//role_Definition_Record.Id = role_Definition_Row.Id;

// You are setting the Name variable of your role_Definition_Record variable
role_Definition_Record.Name = role_Definition_Row.Name;

// Here's where you need to start making changes
// Lists need to be instantiated before using methods like add(), otherwise you'll run
//   into a null pointer exception
role_Definition_Record.memberTypes = new List<DataDef.RD_MemberTypes>();

// Now that you've instantiated the list, you can go into your inner loop and do your
//   processing, and then add memberTypes to your list
for (Membership_Type_Role__c MTR_Row : lstMembership_Type_Role)
{
    DataDef.RD_MemberTypes rd_memberTypes_record = New DataDef.RD_MemberTypes();
    rd_memberTypes_record.id = MTR_Row.id;

    // Once you've finished with each loop iteration, you'll lose the instance of 
    //   rd_memberTypes_record.
    // That is, unless you are using a variable that has a scope that extends outside
    //   of this for loop.
    // Most times, you'll want to store records you create/modify in some sort of collection
    //   (since you can go through this loop more than once).
    // Lucky for us, you already have that in role_Definition_Record.memberTypes
    // The thing you "add" to a list needs to be the same type as the list (or a subtype thereof)
    // Thus, storing the rd_memberTypes_record variable is appropriate, because its type
    //   (DataDef.RD_MemberTypes) matches the type of the List you're using
    role_Definition_Record.memberTypes.add(rd_memberTypes_record);
}

// Do your serialization outside of the loop, once everything has been added to your list
```

Comment: I partially understand what you are saying but I am not understanding the syntax.

Comment: List<DataDef.RD_MemberTypes> RD_memberTypes_record = New List<DataDef.RD_MemberTypes>();
for (Membership_Type_Role__c MTR_Row : lstMembership_Type_Role)
{
 RD_memberTypes_record.id.add(MTR_Row.id);
}

Says Variable does not exist.  something wrong with the way I am adding?

Comment: @JayantDas Did you perhaps mean to comment on the question itself rather than my answer?

Comment: @DerekF - And you're absolutely right. My Bad. That was the intention. Didn't realize because of a blocked view, where I was commenting. Let me add this on the the question too.

Comment: @Daryn I've updated my answer to be more explicit. As a general tip, putting code into comments doesn't work too well (unless it's a short, one-liner). Things like that are better of as an edit to your question (where space isn't nearly as limited, and your formatting options are more numerous). A notification won't go out when you edit your question though, so adding a comment and @-mentioning someone is still helpful (if you want to let someone know that you've updated your question and are still stuck)

Comment: I understand now.  It took me a little longer to wrap my head around what you were saying but I was able to finally put it all together.  It is working now.  Thank you so much.